# how can i dynamically modify an SQL query in Java?

Tags: java, mysql

i'm making a Java program that contains a search engine feature to show the records from the database according to different criterias selected by the user out of comboboxes. I need to be able to modify the WHERE conditions of an SQL query according to what the user has selected. If he hasn't selected any value from the comboboxes then the default would be WHERE=1, if he has selected criteria from one combobox then override the variable so the 1 change it to WHERE `state`=`oklahoma` for example, and he selects 2 or more just keep concatenating them: WHERE `state`=`oklahoma` AND `gender`=`male`, and so on with as many comboboxes he sets.

i've tried to do this but i've read there are libraries that can make this easier but i don't know any, if this can be done with a library please name it and show the code to do it please

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: Google [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) - that's the way to go (safer both from security as well as from data binding perspectives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the combo box number `i` is selected then `isSelected[i]=true`.
2. `content[i]` is the value of the combo box number `i`.

**First Solution**

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement
                       (“SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE
                            state LIKE ? AND gender LIKE ?″); // AND ...



for(int i=0; i<n; i++) // n number of combo boxes
   if (!isSelected[i])
      ps.setString(i+1,"%");
    else
      ps.setString(i+1,content[i]);
 ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

**Second solution**

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement
                   (“SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE (? OR
                        state=?) AND (? OR gender=?)″); // AND ...

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {// n number of combo boxes
    ps.setString(2*i+1,content[i]);
    ps.setBoolean(2*i+2,isSelected[i]);
 }
 ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: i have 7 comboboxes and so my statement needs to change from a WHERE 1 that will just retrieve anything to a WHERE that includes 7 different conditions.    With your example how can i input a WHERE 1? (nothing selected on the comboboxes)

Comment: @AndresMiguel you have to use `WHERE state LIKE ?` and then put in `%`

Comment: @MChaker i tested it in phpmyadmin and it gives me the results i need, now i'll write it into java. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome (+1 already). I forgot to mention, that you have to escape `_` (matches 1 character) and `%` now and maybe also double `'`(?) if it appears in the state or somewhere else. @AndresMiguel you can accept the answer if it works ;-)

Comment: @MChaker i need more info to understand how it works, what does the setBoolean do in the second solution? how does it pass the value of the combobox to the loop? and please show where are the comboboxes called into the loop (there's just the number of the comboboxes but they aren't declared or called).  maraca I'm waiting for more clarification because MChaker edited a new solution and i don't understand it well

Comment: It is up to you to set values of the table `isSelected` and the table `content`. In other words, check with some java code if combo box number i is selected, then set `isSelected[i]=true` and `content[i]` to the value of combo box number i. Once the two tables are set correctly, you can use the solution given above. @AndresMiguel